# How to avoid local variable and subquery to return child records from child table

Tags: sql-server

I have the stored procedure in SQL Server. I have two tables a and b. The B table has the foreign key AId to the table A to its primary key Id. I need to return records from parent table A filtered by name and and the same time the records from the child table they are associated by its id record of table A. I implemented as I listed.  Is there a way to use the id from the query for the second query? Can I avoid subqueries and left joins?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetByName]
    (@name NVARCHAR(255))
AS  
BEGIN
    SELECT
        [a].[Id],
        [a].[Name]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[a]
    WHERE 
        [a].[Name] = @name;
    
    DECLARE @aId INT = (SELECT TOP (1) [Id] FROM [dbo].[a] 
                        WHERE [Name] = @name);

    SELECT
        [b].[Id],
        [b].[AId],
        [a].[Name]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[b] 
    LEFT JOIN 
        [dbo].[a] ON [b].[AId] = [a].[Id]
    WHERE 
        [b].[AId] = @aId;
END;
```

Is there a way to use the id from the query for the second query? Can I avoid subqueries and left joins?

Comment: Why not just `... WHERE [ag].[AccountGroupId] = (SELECT TOP (1) [Id] FROM [dbo].[a] WHERE [Name] = @name)`? What did you try?

Comment: Where is the sub query? Also how is the proc working as the second select where clause is referencing an object `ag` that does not exist? What is the purpose of the proc? You SELECT based on `@name` then do not use those results. You then pick the first record in a random attempt. You may want to research how the `TOP` operator works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I tried the subquery as condition `WHERE [b].[AId] = (SELECT TOP (1) [Id] FROM [dbo].[a] WHERE [Name] = @name);  ` But it works long, maybe is there a way to use id from the first query?

Comment: I need to return row from parent table A filtered by name and its child records from child table B. This is what the proc is supposed to do.

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s Annoyingly, you can't use `SELECT @variable =` in the same query as columns which are going back to the client.

Comment: @Charlieface: what are you referring to? I haven't said anything like that .... I only pointed out that the `sp_` prefix is a big no-no ....

Comment: @marc_s Just thought you might be interested in that tidbit. It would have simplified this a lot `SELECT Id, Name, @Id = Id FROM...` is not allowed

Answer (score 2):

If the `Name` field is a unique key (and consequentially the result of the first query is a single row) you could use scalar variables, like in the following example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetByName](@name NVARCHAR(255))
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id INT;
    DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(MAX);
    
    -- Save the result to avoid recalculate it again
    SELECT @Id = [Id], @Name = [Name]
    FROM [dbo].[a]
    WHERE [Name] = @name;
    
    SELECT [Id] = @Id, Name = @Name; 
    
    SELECT
        [b].[Id],
        [b].[AId],
        Name  = @Name
    FROM [dbo].[b] 
    WHERE [b].[AId] = @Id;
END;
```

If the name is not uinique you could use a table variable or a temporary table (if the returned dataset is big) to store the results and reuse next:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetByName](@name NVARCHAR(255))
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @mainResult TABLE (Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(MAX));
    
    -- Save the result to avoid recalculate it again
    INSERT INTO @mainResult
    SELECT [Id], [Name]
    FROM [dbo].[a]
    WHERE [Name] = @name;
    
    SELECT *
    FROM @mainResult    
    
    SELECT
        [b].[Id],
        [b].[AId],
        [a].[Name]
    FROM [dbo].[b] 
    JOIN @mainResult [a] ON [b].[AId] = [a].[Id];
END;
```

Comment: I just updated the second solution using direct join to table variable

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use the solution below.

Using your original stored procedure, if you had two records with `Name=Bob`, your second dataset would only return b records for MAX(Id). The solution offered here would return b records for all Id values with a matching 'Name' value.

NOTE: If your data won't have duplicate Name values, I would suggest returning the value 'Id' as an output parameter. By doing so, someone that is calling your stored procedure knows that when you pass in @Name you only get one @Id returned.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetByName](@name NVARCHAR(255))
AS BEGIN
SELECT
    [a].[Id],
    [a].[Name]
FROM [dbo].[a]
WHERE [a].[Name] = @name;

SELECT
    [b].[Id],
    [b].[AId],
    [a].[Name]
FROM [dbo].[b] LEFT JOIN [dbo].[a] ON [b].[AId] = [a].[Id]
WHERE [a].[Name] = @name;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Is there a way to use the id from the query for the second query? Can I avoid subqueries and left joins?

Comment: You could -- but you'd be bending the system to work in a way it doesn't want to.

Comment: Actually, no. You cannot. There are several ways to accomplish what this SPROC does, but the specific thing you asked cannot be done. If we were chatting, I'd ask why do you think you need to do what you're asking to do. I think you're trying to solve a problem  that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You could SELECT @aId = Id FROM a WHERE Name=@@name, then use @@aid in Query2. But Query1 would no longer return a dataset (because it's assigning a value to a variable). That's also wordier than doing the solution I proposed.